# Deploying Lambda Function Using AWS IoT GreenGrass On Jetson Nano

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-iot-greengrass

I'm new to AWS IoT Cloud Services, I've created a lambda function that is triggered whenever any image is uploaded in the bucket associated with it and its working fine on AWS, After deploying it using IoT GreenGrass as component on my Core Device Jetson Nano, I'm little confused that how the deployed component will be triggered on jetson device to achieve the same functionality as AWS lambda function.
The actual working of lambda function is to get the newly uploaded data from bucket and send it to the streamlit API running on EC2 instance.

I have tried to deploy the lambda function and its depedencies along with it but I am not getting any response in the log file on jetson. The log file also contained the errors in the first try, like no module name requests than i deployed it along with its depedencies that solved this Module Error but didn't get the response like any image is being saved or sent to API.

Answer (score 0):

You're mentioning "Lambda functions AWS IoT Greengrass" means you're trying this on AWS IoT Greengrass v1; which is entered the extended life phase on June 30, 2023. You can confirm the announcement [here on top of the official docs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v1/developerguide/what-is-gg.html) So, you better to move this practice to AWS IoT Greengrass v2 to stay up to date with service integrations.

Regarding your question "having a similar functionality on edge with AWS IoT Greengrass" can be possible with [custom components.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/create-components.html) I see that your use case involves interacting with AWS services (reading from Amazon S3 or similar); you can use Token Exchange Service; which is another component that provides temporary AWS credentials to your components. [You can check this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/interact-with-aws-services.html) to see how to build components that interact with AWS services.